# AT commands Module SIM7000E

Tags: gsm, at-command, sim800

I am programming some functions in a STM32 board. This functions consist in sequences of AT commands, which are sent over UART to the SIM7000E module, to do different tasks. The module uses a SIM with GSM.

The configuration function sends the following commands:

```
AT+CPIN=1234
AT+CREG=1
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CIPMUX=0
AT+CSTT="vpn","user","password"
AT+CIICR
AT+CIFSR
```

Now I want to program a function to check if the module is consuming network data after the configuration function. I am not sure whether I should check CREG, CGATT, CIICR or other command.

So the question is: In which point is the SIM consuming network data?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think It starts consuming data after the AT+CSTT command. Until the AT+CSTT command,  module does not have the GPRS connection. After the AT+CSTT commands it is open to GPRS calls.

On the other side, even if you have an unvalid SIM card before the attaching the network, you can not know that you have data packet or not. I think like that I am not %100 sure but, I suggest like that.